# Cannot figure out what element header color is in wordpress theme

Tags: themes, css

good people,

I am trying to help out a local small business with setting up a simple Wordress site. I am trying to change the color of the header from blue to black and I was able to do part of it, but there are bits of it on the left and right that I can't find what ID or class they fall under in order to apply a custom CSS style:

http://norcalaviationservices.com/

If anyone could point me to the correct CSS ID or class or show me how to find them myself so that I could change them to black I would really appreciate it!

Thanks much,
Ricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your browsers **Inspector** via it's **Developer Tools** to hover-and-reveal the class andor id name(s) of all html elements on a webpage.

[image: inspector]

Here's some links to popular browsers and how to get started with the tool

- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/Web_Inspector_Tutorial/EnableWebInspector/EnableWebInspector.html

For your site, I believe css of

```
#site-navigation { background: black !important; }
```

will do what you're after

Comment: I guess I should have commented that the code inspector is how I found the class of the element I was able to change the color of and that I wasn't able to find the correct element with that tool-- it looks like you found it pretty easily, don't know why I had so much trouble! Anyway, thank you very much! Your help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: sometimes because of `float`s, `position`s, or `z-index`s some of the elements aren't hover-able with inspector. However, if you hover or click the element in the element tree (as Ive done in that gif) it shows these un-hover-able elements. The Styles panel on the right also then shows the blue background definition - confirming `#site-navigation` was the right one.